# Column names as rows with conditon in R

Tags: r

I'm failing to find solution so I wonder if someone could help. This is matter of few seconds for most of you.

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,4),rep(2,1),rep(3,2),rep(4,3)),rep("Name",10),rnorm(10,2,2),rbinom(10,2,0.7),rexp(10,2),rnorm(10,0,1),
             rgamma(10,2,7),rnorm(10,3,2),rexp(10,5))
colnames(df) <- c("id","Person","X2012","X2011","X2010","X2009","X2013","X2008","X2007")
df$X2007[1:4] <- NA;df$X2008[1:4] <- NA;df$X2011[1:4] <- NA;df$X2012[5:5] <- NA;df$X2013[5:5] <- NA
df$X2011[5:5] <- NA;df$X2007[5:5] <- NA;df$X2008[5:5] <- NA;df$X2009[5:5] <- NA;df$X2013[5:5] <- NA
df$X2012[6:7] <- NA;df$X2011[6:7] <- NA;df$X2013[6:7] <- NA;df$X2009[6:7] <- NA;df$X2010[6:7] <- NA
df$X2008[8:10] <- NA;df$X2007[8:10] <- NA;df$X2008[8:10] <- NA;df$X2013[8:10] <- NA;df$X2009[8:10] <- NA
```

Preview of the above data:

```
> df
      id Person     X2012 X2011      X2010      X2009     X2013    X2008     X2007
  1   1   Name  1.0235950    NA 0.97326338 -0.3755807 0.7672341       NA        NA
  2   1   Name  0.1920131    NA 0.08904475 -0.5014424 0.2120472       NA        NA
  3   1   Name  1.2191632    NA 0.04186686  0.4966126 0.3395579       NA        NA
  4   1   Name  3.6281268    NA 1.63105614  1.5208809 0.2904623       NA        NA
  5   2   Name         NA    NA 0.34680106         NA        NA       NA        NA
  ....
```

Preview of what I would like to have:

```
> df.ok
    Year  id Person      X2012 X2011      X2010      X2009     X2013    X2008     X2007
1  X2009  1   Name  1.0235950    NA 0.97326338 -0.3755807 0.7672341       NA        NA
2  X2010  1   Name  0.1920131    NA 0.08904475 -0.5014424 0.2120472       NA        NA
3  X2012  1   Name  1.2191632    NA 0.04186686  0.4966126 0.3395579       NA        NA
4  X2013  1   Name  3.6281268    NA 1.63105614  1.5208809 0.2904623       NA        NA
5  X2010  2   Name         NA    NA 0.34680106         NA        NA       NA        NA
...
```

Basically, I'm after creating new column vector out of the column names given the numeric value corresponding to the column vector. Entry with NA means the year is not to be used for the given row.

EDIT: Dataset update:

```
my.vec <- c(1,"Activa","","","","","","","")
df <- rbind(df[1:4, ], my.vec, df[5:nrow(df), ])

df[,3:ncol(df)] <- apply(df[, 3:ncol(df)],2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
df[,2] <- rep("Name",nrow(df))
```

So now there is additionally 1 more row just before each id. How to handle this now?

Comment: From `df` you want to get `df.ok`?

Comment: yes please. I think I'm going to post the results too, but I didn't want to enter too much data into this question.

Comment: Let me understand your problems better... Why the first row of column `Year` of `df.ok` data.frame is "X2009"?

Comment: We have 4 rows for the give id, and we have 4 column names with numeric values (rest is NA). The lowest value is year X2009 so basically the data start with the year 2009 and the highest year 2013.So we have 2009,2010,2012,2013. The is no 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Year = rep("", nrow(df))
cols = colnames(df[,-c(1:2)])
for (id in unique(df$id)) {
  # rows should match id AND should have at least a numeric value:
  rows = df$id == id & apply(!is.na(df[,cols]), 1, any) 
  isYearOk = !is.na(apply(df[rows, cols], 2, sum))
  Year[rows] = sort(cols[isYearOk])
}
cbind(Year, df) # This is equal to df.ok

# Test: 
all(Year == df.ok$Year) 
# TRUE
```

Comment: See EDIT: Your solution is perfect for the sample data. Unfortunately, I have on a real dataset additionally one more row before each id. Could you please show me how to deal with it now? Many thanks!

Comment: To deal with this, I've only needed to change the variable `rows`. It identifies rows with matched ids and rows that have at least a numeric value among the year columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible approach:

```
## Identify the non-`NA` values, make necessary adjustment
matches <- which(!is.na(df[-c(1, 2)]), arr.ind=TRUE)
matches[, "col"] <- matches[, "col"] + 2

## Create a `data.frame` from which we can aggregate the
##   sorted column names according to the "id" variable
matches <- data.frame(matches, 
                      Year = names(df)[matches[, 2]],
                      ID = df$id[matches[, 1]])

## Aggregate and retain only the unlisted aggregated values
Year <- unlist(aggregate(as.character(Year) ~ ID, matches, 
                         function(x) sort(unique(x)))[[2]], use.names=FALSE)

## Bind that back with the original data
cbind(Year, df)
#     Year id Person     X2012 X2011      X2010      X2009     X2013     X2008      X2007
# 1  X2009  1   Name  2.724841    NA 0.57090153  0.2346739 0.1861127        NA         NA
# 2  X2010  1   Name  1.604744    NA 0.54476273  1.4647495 0.1477001        NA         NA
# 3  X2012  1   Name  0.887420    NA 0.03375393 -0.7514787 0.1252799        NA         NA
# 4  X2013  1   Name  1.827136    NA 2.48897284  1.3697001 0.1026063        NA         NA
# 5  X2010  2   Name        NA    NA 0.70943724         NA        NA        NA         NA
# 6  X2007  3   Name        NA    NA         NA         NA        NA -4.196199 0.00789531
# 7  X2008  3   Name        NA    NA         NA         NA        NA  5.853701 0.16814434
# 8  X2010  4   Name  2.887311     1 0.64874998         NA        NA        NA         NA
# 9  X2011  4   Name -0.610759     2 0.74106815         NA        NA        NA         NA
# 10 X2012  4   Name  1.827282     2 0.25219805         NA        NA        NA         NA
```

Comment: I'm getting this error on the sample data `df`: Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'closure'